# Storing temperature for cooked omelette

Tags: food-safety

Is it okay to store cooked omelette for 1 week?

Secondly, at what temperature it should be stored ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How long can I store a food in the pantry, refrigerator, or freezer?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/21068/how-long-can-i-store-a-food-in-the-pantry-refrigerator-or-freezer)

Answer (score 1):

You could keep it frozen for longer than a week, but by the time you reheated it, it would be like rubber.
I wouldn't attempt more than a couple or three days in the fridge.

The only way I can think to keep anything omelette-like would be like a Spanish tortilla - maybe it's the potato & onion that changes the texture, but that is fine after being cooled then re-heated.